# PDO queries do not return all results with hyphens

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite

## Setting

I have a website that reads the location from the url and runs a database query on that location.  For the majority of locations this does not cause an issue, however there a few location that the search fails for.  These locations all contain one or more hyphens in the location name but there is a far larger number of such locations with a hyphen that works.

## Investigation

Investigating the issue I found something very surprising, firstly if I ran the query being executed from the command line or sqlite manager the query would return the correct row but if I ran the query via PDO it would return no results.  Even if I ran a like query with LIKE 'w%' it would still fail to return the row with the correct value (though a number of other rows would be returned.

## The Code

```
$db = new PDO($connectionString);
$query = "SELECT name, page FROM stations WHERE page = 'warragul-(nilma-north)'";
$sql = $db->prepare($query);
if (!$sql) {
    $error = $db->errorInfo();
    throw new Exception($error[2], $error[1]);
}
$sql->execute();
$result = $sql->fetchAll();
```

What I have tried

I tried some basic things like using different quotes, bound parameters.
Second I tried look at the hex values in my php and database, but return the same value: 77 61 72 72 61 67 75 6C 2D 28 6E 69 6C 6D 61 2D 6E 6F 72 74 68 29.
Where 2D is the dash value.  I checked this 2D value against another row which did not have this issue and it also used 2D before.  I expanded my search and found some more rows that would not return a value with any sort of text search on the page field such as:
banana-bank
larapuna-(eddystone-point)
port-kembla-habour
I could not find any pattern between them except the hyphens.
Some examples that worked are:
julia-creek
mount-nowa-nowa
st-kilda-harbour-rmys

## What I need

Ideally I would like to understand the issue and what is causing it.  But I will settle for any solution that stops this behaviour and returns the row with the results.

Note: This table and all it rows do not appear to have any issues except when running this query which is the only query to use page in the where clause.

EDIT: I have tried running the same logic with the SQLite3 library which has the exact same behaviour.

EDIT: The assumptions made for this question were incorrect and PDO was connecting to the wrong database causing this issue.  See answer below.

Comment: Have you tried using prepare statements in a bit different way?^^ example: `$query = "SELECT name, page FROM stations WHERE page = :page"; $sql = $db->prepare($query); $sql->execute(array(':page' => $page));` or something like that. Another way to do this would be using bindParam().

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion unfortunately it produces the same result in that it still fails for the problematic row but works for other locations.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this question was based on mistaken assumptions.

The connection string being passed was referring to an older version of the database, similar enough that most locations were unaffected but not completely identical causing a problem for some locations.  Correction the value for the connection string being passed seems to have fixed the issue.